# How to prevent ngInfiniteScroll from being triggered when scrolling up

Tags: angularjs, nginfinitescroll

I am trying to implement ngInfiniteScroll and it works fine when I am scrolling down. But, I want to prevent it from triggering when I scroll up when scroll position is near the bottom. Any help ?

Comment: See this if it is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859207/how-to-prevent-nginfinitescroll-from-being-triggered-multiple-times-after-the-in

Answer (score 1):

set some object like `isScrollUp=true` when somebody scroll up and place that object in `infinite-scroll-disabled='isScrollUp'`

Comment: I am already disabling the infinite scroll when I am fetching the data from server. Now, I have to distinguish between scroll up and scroll down. When scroll position is near the bottom and if user scrolls the page up, then I have to prevent nginfinitScroll from triggering.